# Escaping wildcards in LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

How do I escape wildcards (`_` and `%`) when using a SQL `LIKE` operator in Oracle?

I came to a silly issue today. I need to search for the presence of an underscore `_` on a varchar column using `LIKE`. It doesn't work -- as expected -- since underscores are wildcards according to SQL. Here's my (simpified) code:

```
create table property (
  name varchar(20),
  value varchar(50)
);

insert into property (name, value) values ('port', '8120');
insert into property (name, value) values ('max_width', '90');
insert into property (name, value) values ('taxrate%', '5.20');
```

I tried the following queries in PostgreSQL and they return the rows I want:

```
select * from property where name like '%\_%'; -- should return: max_width

select * from property where name like '%\%%'; -- should return: taxrate%
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work in Oracle 12c. Is there a "standard" way of escaping wildcards? Or at least something that works in Oracle?

Comment: You should use the unicode representation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [the `escape` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-3FA7F5AB-AC64-4200-8F90-294101428C26)

> You can include the actual characters `%` or `_` in the pattern by using the `ESCAPE` clause, which identifies the escape character. If the escape character precedes the character `%` or `_` in the pattern, then Oracle interprets this character literally in the pattern rather than as a special pattern-matching character.

So you can do:

```
select * from property where name like '%\_%' escape '\';

NAME                 VALUE                                             
-------------------- --------------------------------------------------
max_width            90                                                

select * from property where name like '%\%%' escape '\';

NAME                 VALUE                                             
-------------------- --------------------------------------------------
taxrate%             5.20
```

Comment: As an somewhat related note, in MySQL there's a slight variation (need to escape the backslash): ... escape '\\';

Comment: Also perhaps worth mentioning, you don't have to use the backslash character.

Comment: Well, yes, the clause is specifying the escape character to use... though most examples do seem to default to a backslash. Could also mention that you can search for the escape character itself by repeating it (shown in the docs with `@` and `@@`).